# Nginx "Connection reset by peer" due to fire-and-forget HTTP request?

Tags: nginx, axios

I have an app running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and I see a lot of errors in the nginx log like this:

```
failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

These all seem to be related to one API POST. This particular call is meant to be "fire and forget" -- i.e., we purposely don't wait for the Axios promise to be resolved.

Could this be the reason for the errors? Perhaps if some of the requests are pending and the user browses to a different page or closes the app?

If so, is there anything I can do about this? Can Axios be configured to tell the server that we don't care about the response, which might prevent this error from being recorded?

Or am I on the wrong path here?